# How to scrape salary for each job post, its url and closing date?

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find the salary, closing date, and URL for each job post on a website. I am successful to the part of getting information on the main page. But I am failing to get information for each job post.
url = `https://www.higheredjobs.com/admin/search.cfm?JobCat=141&CatName=Academic%20Advising`

**expected output:**
df =

|  | title | university | location | study | date | url | salary | closing date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Educational Advisor | Pasadena City College | Pasadena, CA | Academic Advising | 09/04/22 | https://www.higheredjobs.com/admin/details.cfm?JobCode=178087599&Title=Educational%20Advisor | $58,620.12 to 64,628.76 | 9/25/2022 11:59 PM Pacific |
| 1 | Admin and Office Spec III: School of Humanities & Social Sciences | Laurel Ridge Community College | Middletown, VA | Academic Advising | 09/04/22 | https://www.higheredjobs.com/admin/details.cfm?JobCode=178087578&Title=Admin%20and%20Office%20Spec%20III%3A%20School%20of%20Humanities%20%26amp%3B%20Social%20Sciences | $32,000-$48,000 | 09/16/2022 |

**code:**

```
from pprint import pprint
import datetime
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cookies = {
    'CFID': '180615757',
    'CFTOKEN': '64089929988eb934-58E2ACC9-AD21-785B-2AFBCE86106B41FE',
    'visid_incap_2388351': '0Vmr7QpDRvmVw8fbXUJFkB5XEWMAAAAAQUIPAAAAAADtlXunU/D8GLU5VofHHier',
    '_ga_6ZQNJ4ELG2': 'GS1.1.1662315508.15.1.1662315668.0.0.0',
    '_ga': 'GA1.2.147261521.1662080801',
    '_gid': 'GA1.2.1149490171.1662080801',
    'reese84': '3:yMGXsdMquwoCj3IoSFRCMg==:Vf20HwL77P8oWYTTKbE0XigwyQE3d2lLQpPVoZYcoL8SJTmLeqAani+7GspfC2BiJYOOytBlkIp9MewLgs/XbkaiLrSvLnMdZ0aT8/M9FvBohByybnJXNl25ya/yfpGhL9oT1HKMZYnKqSR0Sg8+nHTUEO0/YErJgQmfoeYIT4kmE01S8cndGIemtuGjvq1hzB/D9VAQL7S3idutOumBNu84j5FyCdOBClCJTriE+X9j40lj1swIxFlryTmBAtLHnEvN9M57N4LMb13yuSBaCawrv4fnron0JnUvfKpLU0CXTnpcM9hJNGv9Ekb4Ap43CZDPdeLVzEmj+39wCVtXPtMqBNCU6mPVBSeJCRHyRuQjY+y0Sv5w7ME2LXhT8bEGHyE8yeuxddxvoG51STebu+pb0mSp5n+iKotUEn9h+sA=:WH64twwKGqtE4pUorYOeGylONeXRsfG+3Qe3zAfpdrs=',
    '__atuvc': '65%7C35%2C2%7C36',
    'COOKIESTATUS': 'ON',
    'HIDECOOKIEBANNER': 'TRUE',
    'nlbi_2388351': 'jGGxMFazFBqnU+x+okRrFAAAAAC/AJ/k+R2U+vs5Q4LIRTS7',
    'nlbi_2388351_2147483392': 'PUildkEvtiZ9uje3okRrFAAAAABv1NR/7gPLX7Lc/iS5ei8N',
    'incap_ses_989_2388351': 'mWy+Uq7aLX000xomDaO5DfTrFGMAAAAA6XmB42vG5CO6i609/RhyKg==',
    'incap_ses_468_2388351': 'sDNcR2labTHyNXYlUqx+BipAFGMAAAAAImV2A07lGANZGfpvhvPlLg==',
    '__atuvs': '6314ec0cdbe92a78001',
    '_gat_gtag_UA_12825325_1': '1',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    # 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Referer': 'https://www.higheredjobs.com/admin/',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    # Requests sorts cookies= alphabetically
    # 'Cookie': 'CFID=180615757; CFTOKEN=64089929988eb934-58E2ACC9-AD21-785B-2AFBCE86106B41FE; visid_incap_2388351=0Vmr7QpDRvmVw8fbXUJFkB5XEWMAAAAAQUIPAAAAAADtlXunU/D8GLU5VofHHier; _ga_6ZQNJ4ELG2=GS1.1.1662315508.15.1.1662315668.0.0.0; _ga=GA1.2.147261521.1662080801; _gid=GA1.2.1149490171.1662080801; reese84=3:yMGXsdMquwoCj3IoSFRCMg==:Vf20HwL77P8oWYTTKbE0XigwyQE3d2lLQpPVoZYcoL8SJTmLeqAani+7GspfC2BiJYOOytBlkIp9MewLgs/XbkaiLrSvLnMdZ0aT8/M9FvBohByybnJXNl25ya/yfpGhL9oT1HKMZYnKqSR0Sg8+nHTUEO0/YErJgQmfoeYIT4kmE01S8cndGIemtuGjvq1hzB/D9VAQL7S3idutOumBNu84j5FyCdOBClCJTriE+X9j40lj1swIxFlryTmBAtLHnEvN9M57N4LMb13yuSBaCawrv4fnron0JnUvfKpLU0CXTnpcM9hJNGv9Ekb4Ap43CZDPdeLVzEmj+39wCVtXPtMqBNCU6mPVBSeJCRHyRuQjY+y0Sv5w7ME2LXhT8bEGHyE8yeuxddxvoG51STebu+pb0mSp5n+iKotUEn9h+sA=:WH64twwKGqtE4pUorYOeGylONeXRsfG+3Qe3zAfpdrs=; __atuvc=65%7C35%2C2%7C36; COOKIESTATUS=ON; HIDECOOKIEBANNER=TRUE; nlbi_2388351=jGGxMFazFBqnU+x+okRrFAAAAAC/AJ/k+R2U+vs5Q4LIRTS7; nlbi_2388351_2147483392=PUildkEvtiZ9uje3okRrFAAAAABv1NR/7gPLX7Lc/iS5ei8N; incap_ses_989_2388351=mWy+Uq7aLX000xomDaO5DfTrFGMAAAAA6XmB42vG5CO6i609/RhyKg==; incap_ses_468_2388351=sDNcR2labTHyNXYlUqx+BipAFGMAAAAAImV2A07lGANZGfpvhvPlLg==; __atuvs=6314ec0cdbe92a78001; _gat_gtag_UA_12825325_1=1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    # Requests doesn't support trailers
    # 'TE': 'trailers',
}

params = {
    'JobCat': '141',
    'CatName': 'Academic Advising',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.higheredjobs.com/admin/search.cfm', params=params, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')#'lxml')#
jobs_list = []
for i in soup.select('.row.record'):
   jobs_list.append(dict(zip(['title','university','location','study','date'],i.stripped_strings)))
df = pd.DataFrame(jobs_list)
```

**Present output:**
df =

|  | title | university | location | study | date | url | salary | closing date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Educational Advisor | Pasadena City College | Pasadena, CA | Academic Advising | 09/04/22 |  |  |  |
| 1 | Admin and Office Spec III: School of Humanities & Social Sciences | Laurel Ridge Community College | Middletown, VA | Academic Advising | 09/04/22 |  |  |  |

Problem:

I could not scrap the sub-pages and information for each post. How to scrap sub-pages and required information.

Comment: why did you add the scrapy tag?  You are not using scrapy

Comment: @Alexander I did not use. But I thought someone might have an answer using it. Hence, I used it.

Comment: The job descriptions are not uniform.  Some have close dates some have due dates, some have salaries, some have salary grade, and some don't have any of the above

Comment: @Alexander I agree with that.  Are there any common grounds? If not, I should at least get the URL of each job posting and the URL of the company. Even If I get a salary or closing date for a few job items, that should be fine. I can manually fill in the remaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information on this site is not that uniform, so you will not get a one fits all approach. To point in a direction that may fit your needs, grab the urls from initial page and iterate them to get information from detail page:

**Note:** *List of links in example is sliced to `[:5]`, to get all results from this iteration simply delete slicing*

```
response = requests.get('https://www.higheredjobs.com/admin/search.cfm', params=params, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')#'lxml')#
jobs_list = []
for a in soup.select('.row.record a')[:10]:
    r = requests.get('https://www.higheredjobs.com/'+a.get('href'), params=params, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

    for e in soup.select('span.at'):
        e.decompose()
        
    d = dict((e.text.strip().rstrip(':'),e.next_sibling.strip()) for e in list(soup.select('#jobAttrib strong')))
    d.update({
        'Title':soup.h1.text,
        'Institute':soup.select_one('.job-inst').get_text(strip=True),
        'Location':soup.select_one('.job-loc').get_text(strip=True),
        'Category':soup.select_one('strong:-soup-contains("Category")').find_next().text.strip()
    })

    jobs_list.append(d)


df = pd.DataFrame(jobs_list)
df[['Title', 'Institute','Location', 'Salary','Type', 'Posted', 'Application Due', 'Category']]
```

##### Output

|  | Title | Institute | Location | Salary | Type | Posted | Application Due | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Academic Advisor | Appalachian State University | Boone, NC | nan | Full-Time | 09/04/2022 | Open Until Filled | Academic Advising |
| 1 | Educational Advisor | Pasadena City College | Pasadena, CA | 58,620.12 to 64,628.76 USD Per Year | Full-Time | 09/04/2022 | nan | Academic Advising |
| 2 | Admin and Office Spec III: School of Humanities & Social Sciences | Laurel Ridge Community College | Middletown, VA | nan | Full-Time | 09/04/2022 | 09/16/2022 | Academic Advising |
| 3 | Post-Licensure Instructional Coordinator and Academic Advisor | Illinois State University | Normal, IL | nan | Full-Time | 09/04/2022 | nan | Academic Advising |
| 4 | College Advising Corps (CAC) Adviser | Georgia State University | Atlanta, GA | nan | Adjunct/Part-Time | 09/04/2022 | nan | Academic Advising |
| 5 | Academic Advisor I ( S03944P) | University of Texas at Arlington | Arlington, TX | nan | Full-Time | 09/03/2022 | nan | Academic Advising |
| 6 | Career & Academic Advisor (Part-Time) | St. Petersburg College | Pinellas Park, FL | nan | Adjunct/Part-Time | 09/03/2022 | nan | Career Development and Services |
| 7 | Academic Advisor | Simmons University | Boston, MA | nan | Full-Time | 09/03/2022 | nan | Academic Advising |
| 8 | Asst Director HSC Roanoke | Radford University | Radford, VA | nan | Full-Time | 09/03/2022 | nan | Academic Advising |
| 9 | Academic Advisor, University Advising Center,Tahlequah | Northeastern State University | Tahlequah, OK | nan | Full-Time | 09/03/2022 | nan | Academic Advising |

Comment: Clean solution. You know what, I read your solution, carefully and now I have scrapped `job URL`, `apply URL` myself. I am still figuring out how did you do the scrap? I am curious to know the kind of background or skill needed to write solution like above? I am a Python person doing data analysis. Are you a full-stack developer or something else, so , you were able to write this solution?

Comment: Thanks for the flowers, but I'm not a full-stack nor I would call me any kind of developer. I like challenges and I love structure, patterns, finding ways to simplify things and I learn with and from every post here at stack overflow- Guess the answer is just practice :) Is there a special part I should explain in more detail?

Comment: Hats off to you. You are a true gem. You are an inspiration and proved that no special knowledge or skill is needed to obtain solutions. You made my life easier. The solution saved a lot of my resources. Also, I am trying to extract additional information after carefully understanding your solution.

Comment: I just posted a new question that you might be interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73624429/using-beautifulsoup-to-search-html-for-a-section-and-its-conent

Comment: How do you make the above table? so when you copy it to StackOverflow, it prints nicely as the above table? How do you do it in Python? Thanks

Comment: @Mainland: Check [`print(df.to_markdown())`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown.html)

Comment: Sorry for late response. For some reasons: the `category` is throwing error. `NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.` I just copied your whole code and ran (Google colab). But I am surprised that you got no error.